Unable to find the solution to a two decision variable, LPP, using the algebraic approach.
The problem is given here, with a graphical solution; though am unable to get the given answer by the algebraic approach.
I took the labels for the # of units of the two decision variables (corresponding to the # of product A, B respectively) by : $x_1, x_2.$
The resource constraint matrix is :
$
\left(\begin{array}{cc}
  50 & 24  \\
  30 & 33 \\
 \end{array}\right)
\left(\begin{array}{c}
  x_1 \\
  x_2 \\
\end{array}\right)=
\left(\begin{array}{c}
  40*60= 2400 \\
  35*60= 2100 \\
\end{array}\right)$
Taking: $30*$ row #$1$ (R$1$) $- 50*$ row #$1$ (R$2$):
$
\left(\begin{array}{cc}
  0 & 720-1650 = -930  \\
  30 & 33 \\
 \end{array}\right)
\left(\begin{array}{c}
  x_1 \\
  x_2 \\
\end{array}\right)=
\left(\begin{array}{c}
  2400*30 -2100*50 =  -33,000 \\
  2100 \\
\end{array}\right)$
$\implies x_2 = 1100/31,$ which gives on substitution in the second row ($R2:30x_1 +33x_2 = 2100$):
$\implies 30x_1 +33*\frac{1100}{31} = 2100$$\implies x_1 = \frac{2100*31 - 33*1100}{31*30}$$ \implies x_1 = \frac{65,100 - 36,300}{31*30}$$\implies x_1 = \frac{65,100 - 36,300}{31*30}$$\implies x_1 = \frac{960}{31}.$ 
As it is a maximization problem, so would take the floor values of the fractions obtained for $x_1, x_2.$
So, $x_1 = 30, x_2 = 35.$
Both of these values do not gel with the answer (obtained graphically).
The objective function is the maximization of $z = x_1 + x_2 -50 (=45+5).$ The minimum # of units of $x_1 = 75 -30= 45,$  while the minimum number of units of $x_2 = 95-90 = 5.$
Even the value of $x_1$ is obtained as $= 30,$ which is $\lt 45,$ i.e. the minimum needed value for $x_1.$
Edit: As per the comment by @Paul, there is no feasible solution obtained by the intersection of the constraints represented by the two rows, $R1, R2.$
 There are other constraints too, that need be taken into view, in order to get any possible feasible solution(s), and the optimum one.
The other two structural constraints are:
$C3: x_1 \gt 45, C4: x_2\gt 5$ 
And, get by substituting the value of $x_1=45,$ in $R1: 50x_1 + 24x_2 = 2400,$ the value of $x_2 = \frac{75}{12} = 6.25.$
But, still have a doubt, as the rhs of the constraints given by the first two constraints are in minutes of time available; while the rhs of the last two structural constraints, are in the number of units available; so cannot put all four structural constraints, in a single set of matrices, of the form $AX = B,$ as shown below:
$
\left(\begin{array}{cc}
  50 & 24  \\
  30 & 33 \\
  1 & 0 \\
  0 & 1 \\
 \end{array}\right)
\left(\begin{array}{c}
  x_1 \\
  x_2 \\
\end{array}\right)=
\left(\begin{array}{c}
  2400 \\
  2100 \\
    45  \\
     5 \\
\end{array}\right)$
I mean that the nature of the first two structural constraints, is quite different, from the last two ones; as the first two give the resource usage, and its usage per unit of the decision variable.
While the last two structural constraints, just give the lower limit of the number of units for $x_1, x_2.$

The max in the objective is not the intersection of the two lines you have given. Have another look!

@Paul Thanks, but still some doubt, as stated in the Edit above.

In all of the constraints the variables $x_1$ and $x_2$ are numbers of things, there is no issue with units.

@Paul I meant that the type of units for the first two constraints, are the number of hours; & for the last two constraints, are the number of units of $x_1,$ and $x_2$ respectively. There is simply no way that the number of hours be taken, on the rhs, in the same matrix; along with the number of $x_1/x_2.$

The units divide out, as explained in the answer below. If $3x+2y$ hours $= 4$ hours then we can also say $3x +2y=4$ without reference to hours as $x$ and $y$ have no units.

For constraint $1$:
$50x_1+24x_2$ is the number of minutes we will actually spend on machine A of which we have a budget of $2400$ minutes.
$$(50x_1 + 24x_2) \text{ minutes } \le 2400 \text{ minutes}$$
divide away the units from both sides, we have
$$50x_1+24x_2 \le 2400.$$
Similarly for constraint $3$.
$x_1$ is the number of units to be produces and $45$ is the number of units required to be produced to meet the demand
$$x_1 \text{ units} \ge 45 \text{ units}$$
dividing away the units from both sides, we have
$$x_1 \ge 45.$$
When we write down the constraints, we make sure the units of the LHS is equal to the units of the RHS and we can view them as unitless.

The constraints are inequalities, hence we can write it as
$$
\left(\begin{array}{cc}
  50 & 24  \\
  30 & 33 \\
  -1 & 0 \\
  0 & -1 \\
 \end{array}\right)
\left(\begin{array}{c}
  x_1 \\
  x_2 \\
\end{array}\right)\le
\left(\begin{array}{c}
  2400 \\
  2100 \\
    -45  \\
     -5 \\
\end{array}\right)$$
where the inequality means elementwise comparison.
Another comment is that if we have integer constraint, we do not just round it off to the floor values. Techniques such as branch-and-bound and cutting planes methods are designed for this. The book intends to just covered the real number case for now.

Please see my last comment to the main post, as still there is confusion on mixing different types of units in the $B$ matrix.

they are unitless, we can cancel away the units from both sides.

Request elaboration, if possible with reference too.

the first part of my answer is to explain the unitless of the constraints. Perhaps another famous puzzle might help. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1749856/306553 In this puzzle, you are given a question on the number of heads and number of legs for human and horses. Number of heads clearly is different from number of legs but it is alright to write down some linear relationship between the number of human and the number of horses.

Kindly see my last post that concerns artificial variables, at: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4972521/424260.
