How to solve using Simplex method, an LPP with all negative coefficients for the objective function.
The problem is given in the book titled: Applied Mathematical Programming, by: Stephen Bradley, et. al.
It states: An iron foundry has a firm order to produce $1000$ pounds of castings containing at least $0.45$ percent manganese and between $3.25$ percent and $5.50$ percent silicon. As these particular castings
are a special order, there are no suitable castings on hand. The castings sell for $0.45$ per pound.
The foundry has three types of pig iron available in essentially unlimited amounts, with the following properties:
$$\begin{array} \title{ \text{Types of pig iron }}\\
\,&  \text{ A} & \text{ B      } & \text{         C }\\\hline
Silicon & 4\%  & 1\%  & 0.6\%\\ \hline
Manganese & 0.45\%  & 0.5\%  & 0.4\%\\ \hline
\end{array}$$
Further, the production process is such that pure manganese can also be added directly to the melt. The costs of the various possible inputs are:
Pig A: $\$21$/thousand pounds
Pig B: $\$25$/thousand pounds
Pig C: $\$15$/thousand pounds
Manganese: $\$8$/pound.
It costs $0.5$ cents to melt down a pound of pig iron. Out of what inputs should the foundry produce the castings
in order to maximize profits?
Resource constraint matrix, for the augmented LPP, showing the four structural constraints ($C_1, C_2, C_3, C_4$) is:
$$
\left(\begin{array}{cc}
  1000 & 1000 & 1000 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
  4.5 & 5 & 4 & 1 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
  40 & 10 & 6 & 0 & 0  & -1 & 0 \\
  40 & 10 & 6 & 0 & 0  & 0  & 1  \\
 \end{array}\right)
\left(\begin{array}{c}
  x_1 \\
  x_2 \\
  x_3 \\
  x_4 \\
  x_5 \\
  x_6 \\
  x_7 \\
\end{array}\right)=
\left(\begin{array}{c}
  1000 \\
  4.5 \\
  32.5 \\
  55 \\
\end{array}\right)$$

with $$C1: 1000x_1 + 1000x_2 + 1000x_3 + x_4 = 1000,$$ $$C2: 4.5x_1 + 5x_2 + 4x_3 + x_4 - x_5= 4.5,$$ $$C3: 40x_1 + 10x_2 +6x_3 -x_6 =32.5$$ $$C4: 40x_1 + 10x_2 +6x_3 +x_7 =55$$
And, the $7$ non-negativity constraints for all the $4$ decision ($x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4$), $2$ slack ($x_5, x_6$), & $1$ surplus variable ($x_7$).
Producing exactly $1000$ pounds of castings, & the total
income will be the selling price per pound times $1000$ pounds. That is:
Total income $= 0.45 × 1000 = 450.$
To determine the total cost incurred in the production of the alloy, we should add the melting cost of $\$0.005$/pound to the corresponding cost of each type of pig iron used. Thus, the relevant unit cost of the pig iron, in dollars per thousand pounds, is:
Pig iron A: $\$21 + \$5 = \$26,$
Pig iron B: $\$25 + \$5 = \$30,$
Pig iron C: $\$15 + \$5 = \$20.$
Therefore, the total cost becomes:
Total cost $= 26x_1 + 30x_2 + 20x_3 + 8x_4,$ (1)
and the total profit we want to maximize is determined by the expression:
Total profit$ =$ Total income $−$ Total cost.
Thus,
Total profit $= 450 − 26x_1 − 30x_2 − 20x_3 − 8x_4. $
This also forms the objective function, $z.$
$$\begin{array} {c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c}
\,  Basis & \text{Value of B.V.} & x_1 & x_2& x_3 & x_4 & s_1=x_5 & s_2=x_6 & s_3=x_7 & Ratio\\\hline
z  & -450& 26 & 30 & 20 & 8 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \hline
s_1=x_5 & 4.5 & 4.5 & 5 & 4 & 1 & -1 & 0 & 0  \\ \hline
s_2=x_6 & 32.5 & 40 & 10 & 6 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & \\ \hline
s_3=x_7 & 55 & 40 & 10 & 6 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & \\ \hline
\end{array}$$
With all the decision variables, in the objective function, having positive coefficients (formed due to all decision variables having negative coefficients), am unable to pursue further in the initial iteration of the given LPP, using the Simplex tableau.
Edit: The latter part of the problem, in the book, is here. Also, the book's treatment of the problem, in terms of adding the slack, & artificial variables, is shown page #43/44, & page #45/46.
Edit 2: Tried to take the book's example, as shown in the last link. The two further pages for showing the book's example, are in page #47/48, & page #49. 
This example, starting on page #46 has $x_7$ as surplus in the first structural constraint. Hence, artificial variable: $x_9$ has been added.
In the second constraint, $x_8$ is a slack variable.
But, have few doubts, in the book's approach:

Doubt #1: Why the book's example of page #46, has introduced artificial variables: $x_{10}, x_{11};$ without having any surplus variable, in the last two structural constraints, is unclear.


Doubt #2: Why on page #48, the book has taken the substitution:
$x_1 -x_2 = y_1, x_5=y_3, x_3-x_4= y_2, x_6=y_4.$

Coming back to the OP example:
After adding artificial variables: $x_8, x_9$ to the structural constraints $C2, C3;$ respectively get:
$$C1: 1000x_1 + 1000x_2 + 1000x_3 + x_4 = 1000,$$ $$C2: 4.5x_1 + 5x_2 + 4x_3 + x_4 - x_5 + x_8 = 4.5,$$ $$C3: 40x_1 + 10x_2 +6x_3 -x_6 + x_9=32.5$$ $$C4: 40x_1 + 10x_2 +6x_3 +x_7 =55$$
With objective function being the same as above, i.e.: $z = 450 − 26x_1 − 30x_2 − 20x_3 − 8x_4.$
$$\begin{array} {c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c}
\,  Basis & \text{Value of B.V.} & x_1 & x_2& x_3 & x_4 & s_1=x_5 & s_2=x_6 & s_3=x_7 & a_1=x_8 & a_2=x_9 & Ratio\\\hline
z  & -450& 26 & 30 & 20 & 8 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \\ \hline
a_1=x_8 & 4.5 & 4.5 & 5 & 4 & 1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \\ \hline
a_2=x_9 & 32.5 & 40 & 10 & 6 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & \\ \hline
s_3=x_7 & 55 & 40 & 10 & 6 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \\ \hline
\end{array}$$
But, cannot pursue further, as no decision variable coefficient, is negative in the objective function.

For each constraints 2 and 3 you need additionally an $\underline{\textrm{artificial variable}}$ (keyword!).

You should add the definition of $x_1, x_2, x_3$ and $x_4$, it was not clear without following the link. $C_2$ seems wrong. The total of manganese produced is $450x_1+50x_2+40x_3+x_4$ and we need $450$ of manganese. Same for $C_3$ and $C_4$. For the simplex algorithm, as @callculus42 mentions it, your main problem is that $0$ is not feasible, so you must first find a feasible solution. You need to relax $C_2$ and $C_3$ with the help of artificial variables.

@caduk Thanks, but the latter part of the book, showing the problem, is shown in the Edit, & can cross-check it please.

@callculus42 Please cross-check with the book's treatment of the same, as shown in the link, in the Edit.

@jiten O.K. How can I help?

@callculus42 Kindly see my 'Edit 2'. Am still stuck, and even more than before, as shown there.

@callculus42 Can you please provide an answer to it, using the relaxation of $C_2, C_3$ stated in your comment.


The purpose of introducing artificial variables  is so that we can form the basis easily. Note that the artificial variables are $x_9, x_{10}, x_{11}$. By doing so,  $x_8, x_9, x_{10}, x_{11}$ form a basis. We will drive these variables out from being basic variables by the end of the optimization procedure.

Initially, $y_1$ and $y_2$ does not have a sign constraints, to convert the optimization problem to a canonical form, all the variables should be nonnegative, hence the conversion is being perform. Note that every real number can be represented as a difference of two nonnnegative numbers.


Link to a linear programming calculator

Edit:

$C_1, C_3, C_4$ are given as equalities. (i) By mentioning $0$ is not an initial feasible solution, I am guessing you mean why not just set the non-slack variables to be $0$? Look at the first constraint, you end up having $0=4$ which is not feasible before the artificial variables are being introduced. But introducing $x_9, x_{10}, x_{11}$, now you can set the valaue of $x_8, x_9, x_{10}, x_{11}$ to the RHS.

$w=-x_9-x_{10}-x_{11}$


where expression for $x_9$, $x_{10}$, and $x_{11}$ are obtained from $C_1, C_3, C_4$. That is how they obtain the first line on page 47.

Can I gather that the constraints $C3, C4$ on page #46, have been initially provided as an equality, rather than inequalities, as no slack/surplus variables are present; yet the artificial variables $x_{10}, x_{11}$ are added, in order to form the basis easily; i.e. to form the initial feasible solution (as pointed out by @caduk). But, am still not clear how: (i) $0$ is not an initial feasible solution, (ii) having $x_{10}, x_{11}$ helps, in getting an initial feasible solution.

Request to show how $w = 2x_1 − 2x_2 + x_3 − x_4 − 5x_5 + 3x_6 − x_7 + 0x_9 + 0x_{10} + 0x_{11} − 5$ is derived on the top of page #47; from the objective function $z =  −3x_1 + 3x_2 + 2x_3 − 2x_4 − x_5 + 4x_6,$ on page #46.

Also, want to ask, why for constraint $C1: x_1 - x_2 +x_3-x_4 -4x_5+2x_6\leq 4$ on adding slack variable $x_7$ to augmented form; still need an artificial var, i.e. $x_9$ (pg #46)? Till now the problems are for the maximization of the objective function ($z$), with the rhs of constraints linked by $\leq;$ with no need to add any variables other than the slack variables. It seems that the 'now' introduction of constraints, with rhs being linked with either $\geq, $ or $=$ has caused need to add artificial variables; also for constraints with slack variables, i.e. rhs linked with $\leq.$

See edit. $3$ constraints are equality constraints.
